# What is the purpose of p5js or js processing

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, processing, p5.js

I recently got to know p5js and also heard that processing is similar to it. Basically, p5js is founded on the html canvas and it can draw things on it. I was wondering if its just the simpler syntax for drawing that it uses is the reason for its popularity or does it also run faster or sth else? Because I cant seem to find a reason but that the syntax is easier to understand.

Comment: From the Processing website: "Processing is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. Since 2001, Processing has promoted software literacy within the visual arts and visual literacy within technology.", also see [p5.js community manifesto](https://p5js.org/community/) and [Processing Foundation](https://processingfoundation.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P5.js is a JS library that (I feel) is aimed to make displaying elements and user interaction simpler. Processing is the java version of P5. I am not sure, but I doubt they are faster than natively doing them in JS or java. It is often aimed at beginners, but became popular for lots of reasons, and it is now taught by Khan Academy, along with others, which is spreading its popularity quickly. It is just a helpful library that makes many things easier and quicker.